# Easy way to set the position of x-axis in pandas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a chart, created in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), where I've set the y-axis to range from -100  to -100.

Is there an easy way to have the x-axis cross the y-axis at y=0, instead of crossing at y=-100
(or, how to display the x-axis at the vertical center, instead of at the bottom of the chart)

Solutions I've seen seem to use subplots or [spines](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html), which seem to be overly complicated for my purpose. I am looking for something more integrated with pandas, like passing the `ylim` or `style` argument)

Sample code:

```
from pandas import Series
s=Series([-25,0,70])
s.plot(ylim=(-100,100))
```

[image: chart with x-axis at the bottom]

Comment: can you post your code please, it just makes it easier to visualize your issue even though it is clear what you want

Comment: You can manually draw a line in the middle of the plot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394527/matplotlib-how-to-draw-an-axis-in-the-middle-of-the-figure. But it seems like matplotlib does not have a command to send the xaxis.tick to the middle of the plot. (There is `ax.xaxis.tick_bottom` and `ax.xaxis.tick_top`, but not middle)

Comment: As far as I know there is no such feature available in `pandas`, as the plotting capabilities of `pandas` are very limited compared to `matplotlib`. Also, if you want to have the ticklabels/tickmarks of the x-axis connected to the "middle axis" (also while panning/zooming), then it's easiest to insert an extra spine; take a look at [`mpl_toolkits.axisartist`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#axisartist) for some examples of this.

Comment: That example you link to is probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I have so far is indeed using subplots:

```
from pandas import Series
s=Series([-25,0,70])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_ylabel('percentage')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')       # x-axis where y=0
#ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')     # x-axis at center (not necessarily y=0)
#ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 50)) # x-axis where y=50
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')             # hide top axis
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')           # hide right axis

s.plot(ylim=(-100,100))
```

[image: chart with centered x-axis]

Not sure why the gridline at the bottom is not shown, but not an issue for me

Comment: When I run your code, the gridline at the bottom is actually shown (matplotlib 1.2.1). In this case I would recommend to use `ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')` rather than `ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')`, as the latter places the spine in the center of the `Axes`, not necessarily at y=0, meaning it moves relative to the y-axis while panning/zooming. These are analogous only when the y-limits are symmetric about y=0. Also, you can remove the "floating" tickmarks at the top and right with `ax.tick_params(top=False, right=False)` to get a cleaner look.

Comment: include the import of the `plt` namespace for completion of code example