# How to force zero (0) to the center of an axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot percent change data and would like to plot it such that the y axis is symmetric about 0.
i.e. 0 is in the center of the axis.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,3,6,7,8], columns=['Data'])
data['PctChange'] = data['Data'].pct_change()
data['PctChange'].plot()
```

[image: percent change on default y axis]

This is different from [How to draw axis in the middle of the figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556446/how-to-draw-axis-in-the-middle-of-the-figure). The goal here is not to move the x axis, but rather, change the limits of the y axis such that the zero is in the center. Specifically in a programmatic way that changes in relation to the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw axis in the middle of the figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556446/how-to-draw-axis-in-the-middle-of-the-figure)

Comment: No. That's moving the x axis to align at a different position on the y axis. This is altering the y axis limits to be symmetric about zero.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After plotting the data find the maximum absolute value between the min and max axis values. Then set the min and max limits of the axis to the negative and positive (respectively) of that value.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,3,6,7,8], columns=['Data'])
data['PctChange'] = data['Data'].pct_change()
ax = data['PctChange'].plot()

yabs_max = abs(max(ax.get_ylim(), key=abs))
ax.set_ylim(ymin=-yabs_max, ymax=yabs_max)
```

[image: percent change about symmetric y axis]

Answer (score 1):

One could implement [Gavin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61050768) as a function:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def symmetrize_y_axis(axes):
    y_max = np.abs(axes.get_ylim()).max()
    axes.set_ylim(ymin=-y_max, ymax=y_max)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
y = np.exp(np.sin(x)) - 1.0
ax.plot(x, y)
symmetrize_y_axis(ax)
```

[image: Plot with symmetrized y axis]