# How can I place the y-axis origin at 0?

Tags: matplotlib

In my graph the x-axis extends from -1 to 1, so I'd like the y-axis to go through (0, 0) (where the blue line is). I couldn't seem to find any way to do this either in the docs or here. Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

EDIT: This answers my question perfectly:
[How to draw axis in the middle of the figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556446/how-to-draw-axis-in-the-middle-of-the-figure)

[image: My graph]

Comment: See this. [How to draw axis in the middle of the figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556446/how-to-draw-axis-in-the-middle-of-the-figure)

Comment: This does exactly what I want, thanks!