# Plot with Xaxis vertical and Yaxis horizontal to the left

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I use matplotlib in a way that I can get something like this:

[image]

As you can see X is vertical up and Y is horizontal to the left.

(You can see that in a normal plot this point would be (-5, 3))

These questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/925024/7758804), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31556446/7758804)) do not look at the direction of the Y-axis. **Y positive goes to the left.**

Answer (score 2):

Plot x as y and y as x. Then flip the x-axis so it runs backwards. In my sample code I also add the axis lines, set the limits to match your drawing, and add axes labels.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

x = [3]
y = [5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(y, x)
ax.set_xlim(-7, 7)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 5)
ax.axvline(0, color="k")
ax.axhline(0, color="k")
ax.set_xlabel("Y")
ax.set_ylabel("X")
ax.invert_xaxis()
fig.show()
```

[image]