# How I can get cartesian coordinate system?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to plotting with Python and can't really find an answer to the question: How can I get Cartesian coordinate plane in matplotlib? By this I mean perpendicular reference lines (coordinate axis) ended up with arrows, intersecting at the origin, (0,0), with the origin at the center of the plot.

Think about a a plane for doing high school geomtery, the following is a perfect example of what I need to achieve:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgU7j.png)

Here is my code, I need the graph to be displayed in a Cartesian coordinate system

```
import numpy as np   # 1
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(-6, 6, 0.2)
x = (4*(t*t-1)/(t*t+1))
y = (4*t*(t*t-1)/(t*t+1))
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 5))
plt.plot(x, y, label='Циклоида')
plt.plot(0, 0, 'go', label='O(0, 0)')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('График параметрически заданной функции')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPfsr.png) I expect

Comment: FWIW, I'm not a plotting expert myself, but I tried your code and got exactly the same plot as the first image. What did you get? Please [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips. I also edited to fix the [code formatting](/editing-help#code) for you, as well as adding the library tag (explained in How to Ask).

Comment: Your code produces exactly the chart you describe.  What is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw axis in the middle of the figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556446/how-to-draw-axis-in-the-middle-of-the-figure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your axes **intersecting at the origin, (0,0), with the origin at the center of the plot** then you will have to use spines (and the object-oriented interface).

```
import numpy as np   # 1
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(-6, 6, 0.2)
x = (4*(t*t-1)/(t*t+1))
y = (4*t*(t*t-1)/(t*t+1))
fig, ax = plt.subplots( figsize=(9, 5) )
ax.plot( x, y, label='some data' )
ax.plot(0, 0, 'go', label='O(0, 0)')
ax.set_xlabel('x',loc='right')
ax.set_ylabel('y',loc='top', rotation='horizontal')
ax.set_title('Illustration of centred axes', y=1.08)
ax.grid()
ax.spines["left"  ].set_position( ('data',0.0) )
ax.spines["bottom"].set_position( ('data',0.0) )
ax.spines["right" ].set_visible ( False )
ax.spines["top"   ].set_visible ( False )
ax.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

But if you want arrow heads on your axes then you will have to draw your own.
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html